# Linking my Fluent model to a pre-existing database table

Tags: swift, postgresql, vapor, server-side-swift, vapor-fluent

I've been trying to link up my PostgreSQL database to a Swift Vapor project so I create routes to it. The first table I want to access is a table in `my_database` calls `users`. It has the properties `user_id` (primary integer key) and `created_on` (timestamp with time zone).

I've linked my Vapor project to `my_database` so that I can create new models. However, what if I want access to the pre-existing table `users`. Here's what I've cobbled together from the documentation and a few tutorials:

**My initial model:**

```
final class Users: Model {

static let name = "users"

typealias ID = Int
typealias Database = PostgreSQLDatabase

static let idKey: WritableKeyPath<Users, Int?> = \.user_id

var user_id: Int?
var created_on: Date
}

extension Users: Content { }
```

**My migration (which I think is just a 'blank' migration, just to hook the project to the table?):**

```
struct FirstMigration: PostgreSQLMigration {
static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    return conn.future()
}

static func revert(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    return Future<Void>.done(on: conn)
   }
}
```

**And my configuration:**

```
var migrations = MigrationConfig()
migrations.add(migration: FirstMigration.self, database: .psql)
services.register(migrations)
```

Any guidance much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the migration. You either need to make your model confirm to `Migration` and add the model as a migration or set the static `defaultDatabase` property. Then you should be good to go.

PS - I think you want `entity` not `name` to tell it what the table name is.

Comment: Thanks for your help again @0xTim (you helped getting started with this on Discord too!) 
I've tried doing that and it all looks good, but when I run it in Xcode I get the following warning:
`Fatal error: Error raised at top level: ⚠️ PostgreSQL Error: relation "users" already exists`

How do I overcome that please?

Comment: Are you trying to create the table anywhere? Do you know what line it throws the error on?